# Rails+ActiveAdmin with custom user`s model (without Devise):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using  `ActiveAdmin` with custom `User` model (without `Devise`) and custom `SessionsController`. I successfully installed `ActiveAdmin`, implement the necessary methods, but faced a problem: after the first visit dashboard, the user`s `remember_token` removed from the cookies (I found it in a browser) that leads to the log out user and redirect to the homepage of the site.

In Rails logs , the following changes to the User model:

```
D, [2015-03-06T18:08:38.412548 #29316] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = $1  ORDER BY login ASC LIMIT 1  [["remember_token", "d983c4abdc252ffc04a71260513ace78534a4c2b"]]
D, [2015-03-06T18:08:38.538903 #29316] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2015-03-06T18:08:38.539994 #29316] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["remember_token", "5c40d43f2df2a0dfcbd0bc3a40496bf3eb5bf8a7"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-06 14:08:38.539165"], ["id", 22]]
D, [2015-03-06T18:08:38.593651 #29316] DEBUG -- :    (53.4ms)  COMMIT
D, [2015-03-06T18:08:38.594675 #29316] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = $1  ORDER BY login ASC LIMIT 1  [["remember_token", "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"]]
```

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "Coordinate"
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  config.logout_link_path = :sign_out
  config.logout_link_method = :delete
  config.batch_actions = true
end
```

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
  def authenticate_admin_user!
    unless current_admin_user
      flash[:error] = "Access error!"
      redirect_to root_path 
    end 
  end 

  def current_admin_user
    return nil if signed_in? && !current_user.admin?
    current_user
  end
```

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token();
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token;
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token));
    self.current_user=user;
  end 

  def current_user
    remember_token= User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token]);
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token);
  end 


  def current_user?(user)
    user==current_user;
  end 

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end 

  def sign_out()
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token));
    cookies.delete(:remember_token);
    self.current_user=nil;
  end
```

Please help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to set values `config.logout_link_path = false` in a configuration file ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 1):

current_user is nil. Right?

Seems like you don't initialize it base on your `remember_token` from cookies. You should initialize it in `authenticate_admin_user!` method.

Comment: Right, `current_user` is `nil`. But as it is initialized if cookies are empty?

Comment: "Your application can store small amounts of data on the client - called cookies - **that will be persisted across requests and even sessions**" - from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies). Is it mean that your `remember_token` should be in cookies (Rails parse Cookie header during request and initialize `cookies` property). Try to output `cookies` values and check it.

Comment: After `sign_in` my `remember_token` stored in cookies and available on different pages of my application. But after entering on the dashboard, `remember_token` in the `User` model is changed, and removed from the cookie. Don't know why. But `authenticate_admin_user!` cookies do not contain `remember_token`.

Comment: And yet, I understood the reason for your misunderstanding: `current_user` is not a variable, it's helper (I forgot to specify it in the main post). I updated my question.

Comment: Probably, are you using any browser extension which remove cookies? Try to check it and try to check `Cookie` header in browser request use browser Developer Tools.

Comment: No, my browser does not delete cookies at ease. To be sure, checked in another.
Cookies just cleared using ActiveAdmin controller.